# Windows file / folder based access rights

Tags: windows, filesystems

We have a file on our filesystem, which can be accessed by ALL users if they have the link to the file, although only admins have access on the folder.

How is this possible?

Comment: As you're talking about a link ... your webserver is different from your windows ACLs.

Comment: Sorry - the link is a file based link. c:\onlyadmin\file.pdf. User can open file.pdf but do not have access to c:\onlyadmin\

Comment: No folder "listing files/subfolders" permission?

Comment: In all likely hood you simply haven't setup your permissions properly. Check the membership of those users as well as the file and folder permissions.

Comment: Maybe the execute / bypass traverse NTFS Permission is enabled for everyone group